# Doit-on prononcer la terminaison « ent » des verbes à la troisième personne du pluriel ?

Tags: prononciation, conjugaison

Par exemple :

> « Bla bla bla » dirent-ils.

Doit-on prononcer  *dir-ils* ou *dirent-ils* ? Autrement dit, le *ent* est-il muet ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Un peu des deux ! *Dirent-ils* se prononce [diʁ‿til], en effet, le *ent* est muet, mais est toujours susceptible de déclencher une liaison. C'est le même phénomène qui fait prononcer *des mets exquis* [de mɛz‿ekski] ou *Pont-à-Mousson* [pɔ̃t‿amusɔ̃].

Comment: I have NO idea what the upside down R means in pronunciation guides.

Comment: @Aerovistae [IPA for French](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA_for_French)

Comment: @Aerovistae it is the Français standard realisation of /r/.

Comment: +1 pour la réponse, et accessoirement pour le fait très surprenant ici de connaître la toute petite ville de Pont-à-Mousson ;-)

Comment: Pas si surprenant que ça puisque le nom de cette ville [apparaît](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fichier:Plaque_%C3%A9gout_Pont-%C3%A0-Mousson.JPG) dans de très nombreuses villes de France :)

Answer (score 10):

« *Ils dirent* » se prononce `/il.diʁə/`, mais la dernière lettre « *t* » est utilisée dans certains cas pour faire la liaison : « *dirent-ils* » se prononce `/diʁə.t‿il/`.
À comparer avec le singulier, « *il dit* » se prononce `/il.di/`, et « *dit-il* » se prononce `/di.t‿il/`.

La règle générale c'est que chaque fois que « *en* » est ajouté pour marquer un pluriel, il peut¹ se transformer en schwa `[ə]` après un son consonne (c'est en fait un [*e* caduc](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/e_caduc) qui est plus ou moins prononcé selon les régions, le ton et l'humeur de la personne ; il est souvent inexistant, mais parfois perceptible), le « *en* » reste cependant silencieux après un autre son voyelle. La lettre « *t* » finale se comporte normalement, elle n'est prononcée que lorsqu'on fait une liaison.

—
<sup>1. On le trouve par exemple listé [dans ce tableau](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe%3aPrononciation/fran%C3%A7ais#ee) avec l'exemple « *ils disent* ».</sup>

Comment: Tu as des exemples pout « faiblement prononcé » et « parfois aussi prononcé qu'un [ø] » ?

Comment: @Evpok: Pour faiblement prononcé, dans le sud principalement, les *e* finaux le sont souvent. Par contre t'as raison, il n'y a probablement que les vrais schwas qui peuvent devenir `[ø]`, comme dans « je ». Je vais corriger ma réponse.

Answer (score 5):

Cette terminaison est silencieuse. Et donc dans *dirent-ils*, on entend en effet `[diʁ.til]`. (Le `t` s'entend parce qu'on fait la [liaison](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_%28linguistique%29).)